# SQL Server query - return null value if no match

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm running into a problem that I cannot figure out for some reason. I am trying to write a query that joins two tables, in which a match may not be found in a table. Such as:

```
SELECT 
    Table1.IDField, Table2.IDField
FROM 
    Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Table2 ON Table1.PersonID = Table2.PersonID
WHERE 
    (Table1.IDField = '12345')
    AND (Table2.Category = 'Foo')
```

If there is no match in `Table2`, it's not returning anything. However, I need it to just return a NULL for that column if there is no match and still return the value from `Table1`.

I have changed up the `JOIN` with everything that I can think of, but to no avail.

`Table2.Category` can contain multiple other values, so doing a `OR IS NULL` type of deal won't work.

So, if there is no match for `Table2.Category = 'Foo'`, I am still needing it to return:

```
Table1 | Table2
----------------
 12345 |  NULL
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using `WHERE Table1.IDField = '12345' AND (Table2.Category = 'Foo' OR Table2.Category IS NULL)` **ought to work** exactly the way you describe it

Comment: @marc_s - whenever I modify that WHERE clause to do that, it is not returning any rows at all. I'm running this query in MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Move the condition for `table2` out of your `WHERE` clause and into your `JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
    Table1.IDField, Table2.IDField
FROM 
    Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 
    ON Table1.PersonID = Table2.PersonID
    AND Table2.Category = 'Foo'
WHERE 
    Table1.IDField = '12345'
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
Table2 ON Table1.PesonID = Table2.PersonID
AND Table2.Category = 'Foo'
```

then delete the 'Foo' line from the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in the join per se, but in the requirement in the where clause that match table2.  I've solved this with a where coalese(table2.category, 'Foo') = 'Foo'.  That way if the table2 is null, it will still match.