# Return NULL for missing values in an IN list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
 id | val
 ---------
  1 | abc
  2 | def
  5 | xyz
  6 | foo
  8 | bar
```

and a query like

```
 SELECT id, val FROM tab WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

which returns

```
 id | val
 ---------
  1 | abc
  2 | def
  5 | xyz
```

Is there a way to make it return `NULL`s on missing ids, that is

```
 id | val
 ---------
  1 | abc
  2 | def
  3 | NULL
  4 | NULL
  5 | xyz
```

I guess there should be a tricky LEFT JOIN with itself, but can't wrap my head around it.

EDIT: I see people are thinking I want to "fill the gaps" in a sequence, but actually what I want is to substitute NULL for the missing values from the IN list. For example, this

```
 SELECT id, val FROM tab WHERE id IN (1,100,8,200)
```

should return

```
 id | val
 ---------
  1 | abc
100 | NULL
  8 | bar
200 | NULL
```

Also, the order doesn't matter much.

EDIT2: Just adding a couple of related links:

- [How to select multiple rows filled with constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201170/how-to-select-multiple-rows-filled-with-constants)
- [Is it possible to have a tableless select with multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886449/is-it-possible-to-have-a-tableless-select-with-multiple-rows)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14160958/1007273

Comment: You could left-join with a number-table.

Comment: @hovanessyan it's not a duplicate (well, at least, not of that question) - because that question is about sql server, where sequences exist - which makes a big difference with mysql for this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this trick:

```
SELECT v.id, t.val
FROM
  (SELECT 1 AS id
   UNION ALL SELECT 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 3
   UNION ALL SELECT 4
   UNION ALL SELECT 5) v
  LEFT JOIN tab t
  ON v.id = t.id
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de89f/1).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. But that will be tricky since there are *no sequences* in MySQL.

I assume you want just any selection, so it's:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (SELECT
   (two_1.id + two_2.id + two_4.id + 
   two_8.id + two_16.id) AS id
   FROM
   (SELECT 0 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS id) AS two_1
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 id UNION ALL SELECT 2 id) AS two_2
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 id UNION ALL SELECT 4 id) AS two_4
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 id UNION ALL SELECT 8 id) AS two_8
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 id UNION ALL SELECT 16 id) AS two_16
   ) AS sequence
  LEFT JOIN
    t
    ON sequence.id=t.id
WHERE
  sequence.id IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

[(check the fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7124/2)

It will work as combination of powers of 2 to generate consecutive table of numbers. Your values are passed to `WHERE` clause, so you can substitute there any set of values.

I would recommend you to use application for this case - because it will be faster. It may have some sense if you want to use this row set somewhere else (i.e. in some other queries) - but if not, it's a work for your application.

If you'll need higher values, add more rows to sequence generator, like in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7124/11).

Comment: Could you provide a version that works with my updated example: `id IN (1,100,8,200)`? Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to add more rows to sequence for that (in my sample, maximum will be 32. But you'll need to add more powers of 2 to get higher values). I've updated for case 200 (that is 255 and `two_128`)

Comment: Got it, interesting idea. fthiella's answer looks more straightforward to me though.

Comment: It is, but.. think of it another way: with query above (i.e. sum of powers of 2) you'll need only `log2(N)` to produce `N` rows sequence, while in "plain" case it's .. `N`