# Show all weeks/month include empty count

Tags: php, mysql

I want to listed the number of user login every week. But when the week does not have any user login, the week won't show out.

My query is as below :

```
SELECT *, 
  YEARWEEK(`date`) AS yw, 
  COUNT(`userid`) AS numaction 
FROM `login` 
WHERE `action` = 'login' AND `userid` != 'admin' 
GROUP BY week(`date`) 
ORDER BY `date` DESC;
```

I saw some examples in SO too, but require another week number table. Is it possible to do without the week number table?

For monthly, is it the same? I means without the month table, just by using the `date` from the table.

I did a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a258/1).

Comment: A date table as you mentioned is really probably your best bet.

Comment: Typically, the problem of missing data is handled at the application level. But, yes, a utility table can work too.

Comment: sorry, my bad - needed to change the where clause as i had not used originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also use a virtual table, i just generate it differently. I have a table 'integerseries' that has one column (id) that has 500 rows going from 1 .. 499. This can be used to generate any range of dates. Here we use days.

Fixed - forgot the 'or action is null' test.

```
SELECT *, 
  YEARWEEK(`the_day`) AS yw,
  COUNT(`userid`) AS numaction 
FROM 
    (SELECT
       MAKEDATE('2014', id) AS the_day
    FROM integerseries
    LIMIT 365) AS all_days
 LEFT JOIN `login` 
    ON DATE(login.`date`) = all_days.the_day 
WHERE `action` = 'login' AND `userid` != 'admin'   
  or `action` is null
GROUP BY WEEK(`the_day`)
ORDER BY `the_day` DESC;
```

Comment: I followed your guide. Create a table named `integerseries` with one column `id` and has 500 rows feom 1 to 499. I added `WHERE` condition at your query, but unfortunately, the result displayed not what I wanted. Here is my [result](http://s15.postimg.org/oql8h3hln/sql.jpg).

Comment: @Chin, did you use the query in my answer? It isn't just the where clause that has changed, the 'from' clause joins the two tables together. i have used your test data here on mysql. it returns the results expected. you should be able to just copy and paste the query

Comment: I think it's my fault. I added the `BETWEEN` condition, that's why something else shown up. Still figuring how to choose those weeks in the particular month.

Comment: @chin, my fault completely - nothing to do with you. I missed the where clause out originally. fixed now.

Comment: @chin, you can add any tests to select dates, or any other conditions that you wish. The problem was that i wasn't including the rows that had 'null' data values. This is the default when you add any 'where' clause. Hence adding the explicit test to select them is needed.

Comment: Thank a lot. Your code is fine to me. I'm filtered it when trying to echo out the row by using `if(date('m', strtotime($row1['the_day'])) == 4)`. I'm not sure this is the best method or not, but seems like it's work for me.

Comment: Your code well-organized (at least to me :) ). I just have to edit the `GROUP BY` to `date`, `week`, `month`, or `year` and the result will be grouped nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I recently asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23335440/return-null-for-missing-values-in-an-in-list) and was advised to use a "virtual" table like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (SELECT 0 AS w
   UNION ALL SELECT 1
   UNION ALL SELECT 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 3
   ... and so on...
   UNION ALL SELECT 53) AS weeks
LEFT JOIN login
ON WEEK(login.date) = weeks.w
```

This looks silly, but appears to be the only way in mysql. Of course, the `UNION` part can be easily automated in php.

To address the comment, the following might work:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (SELECT 0 AS w
   UNION ALL SELECT 1
   UNION ALL SELECT 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 3
   ...etc...
   UNION ALL SELECT 29
   UNION ALL SELECT 30
   UNION ALL SELECT 31
  ) AS days
LEFT JOIN login
ON DAY(login.date) = days.w 
WHERE days.w <= DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()))
```

but it's really better to handle things like this on the application level.

Comment: For week and month, i guess this trick still working. But for day, is it possible? Because number of days are different in each month.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar dilema. It's dumb and probably takes more time and much more code than other solutions but here are my tips:

- Scan the table for days/weeks that there was any activity

  ```
  $active=array();
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT date FROM table GROUP BY date");
  while ($p=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) array_push($active,dateformat($p[date]));
  ```

  of course you have to modify the query to fit your date format demands
- Display the data with a for loop based on a timestamp

  ```
  for ($i=$tstamp_start;$i<=$tstamp_end;$i+=$diff)
    {
       $datefor=dateformat($i);
       if (in_array($datefor,$active))
        {
          $sql=mysql_query("SELECT ... WHERE date=$datefor GROUP BY date");
          //do whatever you want with the data
        }
       else
        {
          //display info about no activity that day/week/month
        }
    }
  ```

  For `$tstamp_start` and `$tstamp_end` you can query `SELECT min(date),max(date) ...`, that should get one row with two elements that you can append to the variables
- I used imaginary function `dateformat()`, I don't know how you store date info in your database - you'd have to create it to be able to get the data in the for loop.
- The `$diff` variable stores timestamp difference to jump through days/weeks

I know it's complicated but works for me, I hope you can benefit from it.

Comment: The `date` column I used is `timestamp` format. I stored the `date` using `now()`.